# Formula to get data from previous month in Google Data Studio

Tags: formula, looker-studio

So I'm trying to get the same data (Clicks Jan, Clicks Feb) to display as shown in the picture below. My first guess was to create a new field using the formula feature. Is there anyone that knows what the formula may look like?

The functions list: 
https://support.google.com/datastudio/table/6379764?hl=en&ref_topic=7570421&authuser=0

[image]
[image: Using the "New field" feature]

Comment: You can't do it with the current with Data Studio functions. You'd need to do it in your data source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do you mean in the data source? I use the Supermetrics plugin for my data source.

Comment: I'm not a user of Supermetrics so unsure of it's capabilities but in something like BigQuery you'd create a datasource where the current date was joined to the equivalent date a month previous and have 2 columns - one for the metric in the current month and a previous month version

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula while creating a column to filter out dates in the last month and create a filter using this column.

```
CASE
  WHEN "Date column name" < DATETIME_TRUNC(TODAY(), MONTH) AND "Date column name" >= DATETIME_TRUNC(DATETIME_SUB(TODAY(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH) THEN 1
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Data Studio and need to make the calculated field in sth like BigQuery. As you say you use Supermetrics plugin I searched Supermetrics for BigQuery and apparently it exists (https://supermetrics.com/blog/supermetrics-for-bigquery) or maybe there is alternative data connector that can import your market data into BigQuery. Once in BigQuery you can do very powerful analytics using SQL. There is built-in connector from BigQuery to Data Studio to visualise your final results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way of doing this with Supermetrics. Watch:

1. Go to Google Sheets and open the Addon Supermetrics.
2. Configure the data query as follows:

   - Data source= connect to Google Search Console > Your Property.
   - Select sites > Your property.
   - Select dates > Last Month. (Activate comparison: previous period. Comparison type: absolute).
   - Select metrics: impressions and clicks.
   - Split by: search query.
   - List item
3. Connect that data source into GDS.

You are done. 
[Table on Google Data Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN3UR.png)